# Add different columns from different queries

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, given my 2 different queries  QueryA and QueryB:

```
Table A              Table B
----------           ---------
CONFIGS A            CONFIGS B
----------           ---------
0.432423             0.914921
```

Result:

```
Table C
----------------------
CONFIGS A |  CONFIGS B
----------------------
0.432423  |  0.914921
```

How can i achieve the Table C?

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you need is sql **join** operation. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-set-1-inner-left-right-and-full-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

You have two scalar queries (ie queries that return just one row and one column), and you want the results on the same row.

You can just `select` both resultsets:

```
select
    (<QueryA goes here>) as configs_a,
    (<QueryB goes there>) as configs_b
```